# Fetch all the items under workflow using core service

Tags: 2011, core-service

I want to fetch all the items which are in workflow using core service (.Net).

Browsing through the core service documentation suggested that `ProcessDefinitionAssociationsFilterData` class would solve the problem. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. Please provide pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ProcessDefinitionAssociationsFilterData` will give you a list of the actual workflow process definitions, do the items in workflow. You probably need the `UserWorkItemsFilterData` class.

Take a look at the code in this project

https://code.google.com/p/tridion-notification-framework/source/browse/NotificationService/NotificationService/Worker.cs

You want  something like this

```
    var userWorkItemsFilter = new UserWorkItemsFilterData()
    {
        ActivityState = ActivityState.Started | ActivityState.Assigned,                                               
    };        
    var workItemDataList = new List<WorkItemData>();
    client.GetSystemWideList(userWorkItemsFilter).ToList().ForEach(idObject => workItemDataList.Add(idObject as WorkItemData));  
    return workItemDataList.ToArray();
```

I think if you query this as an admin, you can get all work items rather than a specific user's work items.